# Error in Functional Javascript book example

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js

I'm reading through Michael Fogus' book *Functional JavaScript*, and one of the examples in the book isn't working. Here's the code:

```
function existy(x) {
    return x != null;
};

function truthy(x) {
    return (x !== false) && existy(x);
};

function cat() {
    var head = _.first(arguments);
    if (existy(head))
        return head.concat.apply(head, _.rest(arguments));
    else
        return [];
};

function construct(head, tail) {
    return cat([head], _.toArray(tail));
};

function rename(obj, newNames) {
    return _.reduce(newNames, function(o, nu, old) {
        console.log("o: " + o);
        console.log("nu: " + nu);
        console.log("old: " + old);
        if (_.has(obj, old)) {
            o[nu] = obj[old];
            return o;
        }
        else
            return o;
    },
    _.omit.apply(null, construct(old, _.keys(newNames))));
};

rename({a: 1, b: 2}, {'a': 'AAA'});
// => {AAA: 1, b: 2}
```

All of the functions work properly except rename(). Essentially, the goal it to take an object and return the object with property names updated with the newName object. I don't quite understand it fully, but the reduce method doesn't look like it has the right arguments. Here's the error I get when I call rename():

```
ReferenceError: old is not defined
```

Any help to understand why it's not working would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function rename(obj, newNames) {
    return _.reduce(newNames, function(o, nu, old) {
        console.log("o: " + o);
        console.log("nu: " + nu);
        console.log("old: " + old);
        if (_.has(obj, old)) {
            o[nu] = obj[old];
            return o;
        }
        else
            return o;
    },
    _.omit.apply(null, construct(old, _.keys(newNames))));
}
```

when called, executes

```
_.reduce(newNames, function(o, nu, old) {
    console.log("o: " + o);
    console.log("nu: " + nu);
    console.log("old: " + old);
    if (_.has(obj, old)) {
        o[nu] = obj[old];
        return o;
    }
    else
        return o;
},
_.omit.apply(null, construct(old, _.keys(newNames))));
```

which calls

```
_.omit.apply(null, construct(old, _.keys(newNames)))
```

and `old` only exists inside `_.reduce`’s callback. If it was intended to be the first object, you could use `newNames[0]`.

But I wouldn’t trust a book that puts semicolons after function definitions…

---

Personally, if I were to implement that “functionally”, it’d look something like this:

```
function objectMap(obj, func) {
    var result = {};

    for (var x in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
            var r = func(x, obj[x]);
            result[r[0]] = r[1];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

function rename(obj, newNames) {
    return objectMap(obj, function(k, v) {
        return [newNames[k] || k, v];
    });
}
```

Comment: +1 "I wouldn’t trust a book that puts semicolons after function definitions…"

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestion as to how I should fix it?

Comment: @EmptyArsenal: I’m still not quite sure what it does. Does it take `{a: 52}` and `{a: "b"}` and produce `{b: 52}`?

Comment: Sorry, I added the result to the code. Essentially, it just changes the names of an object property. i.e. This the case of `rename({a: 1, b: 2}, {'a': 'AAA'})` and switches out 'a' with 'AAA' in the object. So yeah, it looks like it does what you expect.

Comment: @EmptyArsenal: I added my implementation. It’s sort of the same idea – do you mind `objectMap` not being as functionalish as the original? :D `rename` certainly is now.

Answer (score 1):

Per @minitech, the issue is that 'old' only exists in the `_.reduce` callback, so when it's called in the `_.omit` function, it is beyond the scope of 'old'. It turns out that there's an easy fix. If you change 'old' to 'obj' (which may have been what the author intended), the function seems to work properly and retains its functional nature:

```
function rename(obj, newNames) {
    return _.reduce(newNames, function(o, nu, old) {
        if (_.has(obj, old)) {
            o[nu] = obj[old];
            return o;
        }
        else
            return o;
    },
    _.omit.apply(null, construct(obj, _.keys(newNames))));
}; 

rename({a: 1, b: 2}, {'a': 'AAA'});
// => {AAA: 1, b: 2} -> success!
```